# what should action='' be set to so that <form> submits to same page?

Tags: html

What should 'action='' be set to so that the same page is used for the submit?

When I do a submit on the following , presently I have:
 action="./diag_system_page_controls.htm"
..but can I just have  action=""  to indicate that I want to re-load the same page?

```
            <span hidden="hidden">
                <form id="SNMP_operation_windmarks_form_id" class="body_t" action="./diag_system_page_controls.htm" method="post" >  
            <!-- A page-to-vxworks windmark field must be <input> and needs id= name= value= 
                    and cannot be used bi-directionally...-->

                   <!-----------  PAGE-TO-MM WINDMARKS GO HERE:   -------------->
                  <!--  EXAMPLE:
                <input id="SNMP_signal_element_id" type="text" name="SNMP_signal_windmark" value="$%SNMP_signal_windmark#$" />
                <input id="SNMP_IP_windmark_id" type="text" name="SNMP_IP_windmark" value="$%SNMP_IP_windmark#$" />
                <input id="SNMP_OID_list_windmark_id" type="text" name="SNMP_OID_windmark" value="$%SNMP_OID_windmark#$" />
                <input id="SNMP_set_data_windmark_id" type="text" name="SNMP_set_data_windmark" value="$%SNMP_set_data_windmark#$" />
                <input type="submit" />                                  -->
                </form>
                 <!-----------  MM-TO-PAGE WINDMARKS GO HERE:   -------------->
                 <!-- EXAMPLE:
                 <br />SNMP_signal_done_windmark:
                <span id="SNMP_signal_done_element_id" >$%SNMP_signal_done_windmark#$</span>
                -->
           </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

A blank action will accomplish want you want but that's generally considered bad form. You can use your server side language of choice to provide the information for you if for some reason the page name is dynamic. In PHP it would look something like:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_HTML5, 'utf-8); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, it should be the same page. While you can leave it empty, it is invalid, and should be avoided. Don't rely on the browser to make the right decision.

Comment: I believe only in HTML5 is it invalid to leave the action field empty. HTML4x just deals.

Answer (score 0):

Use `action=""`.

According to HTML specifications, the `action` attribute value shall be a URL, but an empty string is a URL, interpreted as same-document reference, by [Internet standard 66](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), clause 4.4.

The HTML5 drafts (work in progress) propose to make an empty value forbidden and, on the other hand, make the `action` attribute optional, defaulting the action to the empty string. Rather odd, if you ask me.

Anyway, you can either omit the attribute or set it to the empty string, with the same effect. Setting it looks more informative to me: the author did not just forget it, he intentionally created a same-page reference.